# List Wordpress categories in sidebar with image

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm to list categories with images in the sidebar this is how I do it (and it works) I do this because I've certain categories I do not want to display!

```
<?php $latests = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2&ignore_sticky_posts=1&cat=12'); ?>
<?php echo get_cat_name(12); ?>
<?php while ($latests->have_posts()) : $latests->the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('sidebarcat'); } ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

but I need to copy past that code for every single category... and all this code for only changing a number is a good practice I guess. Is there another way it could be done?

I've tried with a foreach but it seems to be wrong

```
<?php $latests = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=2&ignore_sticky_posts=1&cat=12'); ?>
<?php foreach($latests as $latest) :?>

    <?php while ($latests->have_posts()) : $latests->the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('sidebarcat'); } ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, You can do it like this:

```
<ul>
<?php
$cat_args=array(
//  'include' => '3,6,9', // display only these categories
  'exclude' => '3,6,9', // display all categories except categories 3,6,9
  'orderby' => 'name', // the order 
  'order' => 'ASC' // asc or desc
);

$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
      'showposts' => 2, // how many posts you want to display 
      'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );

$posts=get_posts($args);
      if ($posts) { 
        echo '<h3> <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in: %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </h3> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post); 
?>

    <li>
        <div>
            <div><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('sidebarcat'); } ?></a></div>
            <div><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
        </div>
    </li>


          <?php
        } // close foreach 
      } // close if  
    } // close foreach 
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is like that

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&exclude=3,5,9,16'); ?>
```

So, this will return you all the categories excluding the one you specified. After this, you can get the actual image you want for your categories and all.

Comment: yeah, but I need to get the last 2 posts from every category ... and for sure with that isn't possible.

Comment: If you take the array, do a foreach on this array you will be able to query the last 2 posts of all those categories.